# Installing PDT on Eclipset Classic 3.7 (indigo) always fail

Tags: php, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-pdt

Every time i try to install PDT through "install new software" feature in Eclipse Classic 3.7 (tutorial [here](http://wiki.eclipse.org/PDT/Installation)) i get the following error, after a lot of time fetching and downloading stuff:

> An internal error occurred during: "Install download1". Comparison
>   method violates its general contract!

This is frustrating cause i'm following the tutorial *exactly*. What's wrong with it? How can i check for logs and try to find out the actual error?

This happens on both x86 and x64 version of Eclipse. Tried in a fresh environment, Windows 7 x64, JRE 7 x64 and Eclipse Classic 3.7.

Comment: Have this running with no problems with Eclipse 3.7 and the PDT update site `http://download.eclipse.org/tools/pdt/updates/3.0/milestones/` - on Fedora 14.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved using 3.7.1 from [here](http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/downloads/eclipse3x.php). Getting no problem at all both on x86 and x64 version. Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 0):

I got this error when I was running Eclipse 3.7 on Sun JRE 7 on Debian 6. It is related to synchronizing the updates mirror list. Running JRE 6 fixed the issue for me.

[Synchronization problem in mirror selection](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=317785)

[Can't update Eclipse for EE Developers (Indigo)](http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/243191/)

Answer (score -2):

Last I had heard, a few months ago,  the PDT plugin was no longer being maintained. I keep a separate version of eclipse just for PHP development.

http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-php-developers/heliossr2

Comment: it is still maintained, but it is not packaged as standalone ide

Comment: "Due to lack of a package maintainer for the Indigo release there will be no PHP (PDT) package. If you would like to install PDT into your Eclipse installtion you can do so by using the Install New Software feature from the Help Menu and installing the PHP Development Tools (PDT) SDK Feature from the Eclipse Indigo Repo"

http://eclipse.org/downloads/php_package.php